# how to send a very important number of push notification at once (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, http, tcp, push-notification

I need to send a push notification to all users of my android app at midnight. If there are 100k users, all of them need to receive the notification at 12.00am. I saw that, with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), you can send, from your server, messages with notifications in it, up to 500 message per HTTP request.

My server is in PHP. The problem is that sending HTTP requests with PHP is synchronous. For 100k notifs to send, the last user will have to wait 200 request - response (500 * 200 = 100k) before they gets their notification.

I thought about multi-threading : I could send 200 HTTP request in the same time, each on its thread. But I'm not sure that Firebase services will like receiving so much request in the same time (for Apple Push Notification service, if it receive too much connections in a short timespan, it returns an error and does't proceed the request). Plus, after many attempts and reading on the net, I was not able to have multithreading functions working, but that's for another topic.

So, what would be the best approach ? I could translate everything in C++ and then use multithreading easily there, but i'm lazy to rewrite all my business classes in C++.. Is there any more simple maner I have missed out, to send all my 100k notif to FCM at once  (maybe through a single raw TCP con, like for Apple) ?

Comment: "But I'm not sure that Firebase services will like receiving so much request in the same time" That's not something you'll usually have to worry about. FCM is used to deliver billions and billions of messages per day (not all of them are notifications that users see), so the APIs are designed to handle large volume and bulk very well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was asking because it does causes problems with APNS (for Apple push notifications). So you would do a multithread script sending all batch at once in 200 different threads ?

Comment: Well no, I'd do everything possible to predeliver the messages to each device, and then only display them at the right time. But if that's not possible, I wouldn't worry too much about FCM handling the peak load.

Comment: You can create a Topic, or Group, and send a message to that. FCM will handle distribution of message to devices. more details here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple

Comment: I forgot to mention, I send individual personalized messages to each of my users.. as I understood topics are meant to send same message to a group of users right ?